# Is there a way to map Control + 6 or Shift + Control + ^ to a leader key?

Tags: vim, macvim

`Control + 6` or `Shift + Control + ^` will switch between the current file and the alternate file in vim. Its useful but I hate using the Control key and try to avoid it if possible. However, despite searching and experimenting I can't seem to map to my leader key. I think the problem is with numeric keys and the caret. Anybody have any ideas to get this working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of these work.

```
nnoremap <leader>f <C-^>
nnoremap <leader>v :e #<CR>
```

They are currently mapped to random letters with leader in front as I wasn't sure which ones you wanted. The second one is the functionally equivalent behavior to `<C-^>` according to [`:h CTRL-^`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#CTRL-6). Except that it doesn't work with files with no names.

Without seeing what you tried I cannot tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Perfect, it works great. Thank you. I tried every variation but the correct one. No shift needed, that is interesting.

Comment: @fontno `nnoremap <leader>f <C-S-^>` also works (or seems to on my vim). However The shift isn't needed because you only need the character in the mapping. Not the character sequence needed to produce the mapping.

Comment: ah, ok that makes more sense. Learn something new about the vims everyday. Thanks for your time.