# can I map a key binding to a function in vimrc?

Tags: vim

So originally I had the following config in my vimrc

```
map <F5> :call Compile()<CR>
```

But somehow I feel F5 is not very convenient, so I tried to map it to `<A-q>` or `<A-1>`, which seem did not work. I also tried `<C-q>` and `<C-1>`, seems nothing happened.

So I can not map a function to a key binding?

Comment: To use `<A-...>` you'll need to properly configure your terminal (which is not trivial), or use gvim.  Regarding `<c-q>`. That's odd. Note by the way, `:make %<` (or `:make all` if you have a makefile) is more than enough in most cases. Also, the mapping should be done with `nnoremap` as it can only work in normal mode, and there is no reason to accept "recursive" mappings (some people bind `:` to `;`)

Comment: It is possible to a call a function from a mapping; does your mappings work if they do not call a function? (e.g.: `:map <a-q> :echo "test"<cr>`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to map Control + 6 or Shift + Control + ^ to a leader key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076245/is-there-a-way-to-map-control-6-or-shift-control-to-a-leader-key)

Answer (score 13):

Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

So, `<C-1>` is out, but the other mappings should work just fine; for example:

```
nnoremap <C-q> :call Compile()<CR>
```

You can check that no other plugin cleared / overwrote the mapping via

```
:nmap <C-q>
n  <C-Q>       * :call Compile()<CR>
```

#### Additional tips

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- `:map` covers normal, visual, and operator-pending modes. You probably only want to start compilation from normal mode, so `:nnoremap` is more precise. (And if you later add a visual mode mapping for compiling just the selection, the key is still free for use in that mode.)